# e answer of this problem is for me to change the geolocator version in pubspec.yml to 7.0.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, methods, geolocator

E/flutter (13537): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isLocationServiceEnabled on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)
E/flutter (13537): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (13537): 
E/flutter (13537): #1      _gettinglocationState._determinePosition (package:flutter_app/main.dart:34:22)
E/flutter (13537): 
E/flutter (13537):

Comment: change version of geolocator in pubspec to 7.0.0 instead of 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you get this error when trying to acquire the current position from a background task or isolate.

The problem with this is that with version 3.1.6 of the `geolocator_android` and version 2.1.2 of the `geolocator_apple` (iOS and macOS) the default method channel implementation has been replaced by a platform specific implementation. However since the task is run in a separate isolate which executes without the Flutter engine, the platform specific implementation (in this case `geolocator_android`) is not registered with the platform interface (`geolocator_platform_interface`) resulting in the `MissingPluginException`.

To use geolocator_android version 3.1.6+ or geolocator_apple version 2.1.2+
(these are dependencies of geolocator version 8.0.0) make sure you register the platform specific implementation when the background task is started. Examples on how to accomplish this using the `Workmanager` are:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
   if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
     GeolocatorAndroid.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
     GeolocatorApple.registerWith();
   } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
     GeolocatorLinux.registerWith();
   }

    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  });
}
```

Alternatively if you are running Flutter 2.11+, you can use the new `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` method to ensure all packages are registered correctly:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  });
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1041#issuecomment-1125862107) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98473#issuecomment-1060952450).